# Convert c++ pointer arithmatic to assembly (MIPS 32)

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, mips32

I am trying to convert this c++ statement with pointers into an assembly statement.

```
if (*hopPtr2 != *hopPtr1) 
    goto endI4;
```

I am having difficulty because I cannot think of another way to do this. I get an error at these lines when I run the program, but it compiles successfully.

Any and all help would be much appreciated!!

```
# $t5 is register used for *hopPtr2
# $t4 is register used for *hopPtr1
lw $t5, 0($v1)
lw $t4, 0($v0)
bne $v1, $v0, endI4
```

Comment: Since you load `$t4` and `$t5`, you should use those in the `bne` obviously.

Comment: I'd generate the assembly listing (with as much debug/code generation info as your compiler provides) and then try to figure out what may be the problem.

Comment: It gives me the error at the first line. the lw $t5 line, which is the most confusing to me.

Comment: Which error? The comment gives the impression that the pointers are already in t4 and t5. What's in v1 and v0? Addresses of variables hopPtr1 and hopPtr2? It looks as if you were trying to 'load' t5 into v1 by "lw $t5, 0($v1)".